# Drupal event and subscription

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views

I'm searching a way to make a **calendar** with **events**.

The events could be **subscribed** by authenticated **users**.

When The user is subscribing, he have to **pay** some items (price for the event and for meal). One person can pay multiple meals but cannot pay for multiple people (user can select the number of meal but not the number of places he want to book)

How can I do ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: UberCart Event Registration :http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ME42weiKRoM could be the solution but I don't want to install all that stuff and I need to make 2 or 3 different packs 'lunckbox', 'diet lunckbox', ...

Answer (score 2):

There's a useful prebuilt Feature for this over on GitHub: https://github.com/bobchristenson/commerce_event_registration

You'll need a few modules:
 - Webform
 - Commerce
 - Webform Validation
 - Rules
 - Webform Rules

The last time I used this was some time ago (in fact the last commit on the project was over a year ago), so there may be a few new things to tweak to get it working.

I know it's linked on the GitHub repo, but here's a link to the podcast from Mustardseed about this: http://mustardseedmedia.com/podcast/episode51

Answer (score 0):

for the event subscription part you can use the subscriptions module, the events being a content-type 'event'

```
    https://www.drupal.org/project/subscriptions
```